# GpsLocation: Invalid method declaration; return type required

Tags: java, android, google-maps, main-activity

When trying to integrate googleMaps into my MainActivity following instructions [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/678431/Example-of-using-google-maps-service-and-gps-in-an), the word `GpsLocation`(orange box 6 on linked page) goes red and says- `Invalid method declaration; return type required`.

I know this means it has to be inside of a button or a void or something, but here I have no idea *what* it needs to be in. So please, take a look at my MainActivity, and tell me where I am going wrong.

Here's my MainActivity:

```
package com.lalalaala.mapstest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GoogleMap googleMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (googleMap == null) {

            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                // Changing map type
                //TODO
            }
        }
    }

    public GpsLocation (Context mContext, TextView gpsStatusTextView) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.gpsStatusTextView = gpsStatusTextView;
        getLocation();
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: what didn't you understand of the compile-time error you are getting ?

Comment: I didn't compile.. this is the first hand view(it becomes red and gives warnings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method needs to have a **return type** in your case `GpsLocation` **and** a **name**. Currently you only have a **return type**.

```
public GpsLocation methodName (Context mContext, TextView gpsStatusTextView) {

}
```

not

```
public GpsLocation (Context mContext, TextView gpsStatusTextView) {

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: ohhhh..haha. <!-- here --> is a comment!

Comment: i removed it to prevent further confusion

Comment: @Rainbowteddycoderguy then I revert back to my original answer. A method has to have a name as well as a return type

Comment: Okay, so I understand that I have to name it. How do we do that? I wrote your example and it grayed out